# Ajax not working on file upload?

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I am using express and ajax to upload an image file to server disk.
My express code looks like

```
app.post('/events/upload',function(req,res){
upload(req,res,function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return res.end(err);
    }
    console.log("333333333333333333333333333")
    res.send("File uploded");
});
  });
```

My ajax code is :

```
    $(function () {
    $('#upload-form').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/events/upload',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function () {
                console.log("Uploded");
            },
            error: function () {
               console.log("Not uploded");
            }
        });
    })
})
```

and my html is

```
 <form   method='post' action='upload' enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input id="upload" type="file" class="btn btn-warning" name="userPhoto"/>
     <input id="upload-form" type="submit">
    </form>
```

Now, when i remove the **preventDefault** the image file is being uploded and redirected to "File upload", However, when the preventDefault is there, every logs is being printed like "33333333333" and "$$$$$$$$$$$$$" but the file is not being uploded. Any idea why is this happening.

Comment: Your AJAX request isn't sending any data...

Comment: Ok, i didnt know that, i thought AJAX would use the route handlers internally to handle it

Comment: Googling a bit a more then.

Comment: It does, but you need to include the payload within the request. In your case  you'll need to use a `FormData` object to send the file data. Seee [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously) for more information

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload

Comment: Thanks it worked. :-)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if you want to answer it, i would accept it.

Comment: Thanks for offering, however I already marked it as a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see though, my bad... :-(  Anyway thanks for help. :-)